# Auto Start Application on Startup - Wait for API to be available

Tags: registry, windows-installer, startup, okuma

Alternate title: Auto-run THINC app when control is turned on (run only after OSP NC system started)

I am writing an application for the OSP-P300 control (Running WinXP) and want it to start automatically when the control boots up / turns on. I have tried using a shortcut in the startup folder but that is causing an issue.

When the app runs before the NC software is finished starting, I get errors from my THINC API functions. (The API is not available yet)

I know about the "Okuma THINC Startup Service" program, and have it running on my control. When manually configured, this method takes care of the issue and loads my app at the appropriate time.

My question is: **Is there a way to add my application to the Startup Service programmatically, during the install process?**

Yes, the user can still do this manually, but a check-box option during install that is checked by default would be SO much simpler.

Could it be as simple as adding a few registry keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the startup service that comes on the API disk.
Here is the class I use to register/unregister.
The CReg class I got from here : [RegistryKeyAccess.vb](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/511D570B/359F7F33)

Imports Microsoft.Win32

```vb
Public Class ThincStartupReg

    Public Overloads Shared Sub Register(ApplicationPath As String, ApplicationName As String, AppType As enumAppType, wait As Boolean, LaunchType As enumLaunch)
        Try
            Dim ObjReg As New CReg
            Dim regCreated As Boolean

            If ObjReg.ReadValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\StartupService\", "State") Then

                'Startup Service is installed

                If Not ObjReg.ReadValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName, "Enabled") Then
                    'No entry for this program
                    regCreated = ObjReg.CreateSubKey(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName)

                Else
                    regCreated = True
                End If

                If regCreated Then
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                     "Type", "Process")
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                      "Name", ApplicationName)
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                      "Enabled", "True")
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                      "Wait", If(wait, "True", "False"))
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                      "Type", If(AppType = enumAppType.Process, "Process", "Service"))
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                      "Launch", If(LaunchType = enumLaunch.LaunchOnce, "Once", "Monitor"))
                    ObjReg.WriteValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & ApplicationName,
                                     "File", ApplicationPath)
                End If


            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Overloads Shared Sub Register(ThisAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly, ByVal AppType As enumAppType, ByVal Wait As Boolean, ByVal LaunchType As enumLaunch)
        Dim AppName = ThisAssembly.FullName.Split(",")(0)
        Dim AppPath = ThisAssembly.Location
        Register(AppPath, AppName, AppType, Wait, LaunchType)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub UnRegister()
        Try
            Dim ObjReg As New CReg
            Dim AppName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(",")(0)

            If ObjReg.ReadValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\StartupService\", "State") Then
                If ObjReg.ReadValue(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & AppName, "Enabled") Then
                    ObjReg.DeleteSubKey(ObjReg.HKeyLocalMachine, "SOFTWARE\OAC\Startup\" & AppName)
                End If

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

If you're not sure the install service will be installed you could just add your shortcut to the startup folder and then just loop until the OSP process has started.

```vb
Public Shared Function Wait(Timeout As TimeSpan) As Integer
        If File.Exists("C:\OSP-P\OSPMNGCD.CNC") Then
            Dim startTime = Now
            Dim myProcess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("PNC-P200")
            While myProcess.Length = 0
                If Now.Subtract(startTime) >= Timeout Then Return -1
                myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("PNC-P200")
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End While
            'OSP Started
            Return 1
        End If
        'Simulation mode (not on a machine)
        Return 2
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for pragmatically adding a Startup Item for the THINC Startup Service (TSS) to handle:

Startup of an application via the TSS is controlled by the Registry, in the following Key:

**"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\OAC\Startup"**

To "register" your application to be handled by the TSS, create a sub-key, under Startup,
which names your app:

**"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\OAC\Startup\ScottsApp"**

ScottsApp should then be assigned the following values:

```
    NAME
    FILE
    TYPE
    ENABLED
    LAUNCH
    WAIT
    DELAY
    ARGUMENT
```

**NAME** = The "display name" for your application if it is a Process, or the Service Name if it is a Windows Service

**FILE** = The full path, including the executable name, to your application's executable assembly.  This is internally disregarded if the TYPE value is "SERVICE", as the TSS would then use the NAME value to start the specified Windows Service

**TYPE** = "SERVICE" or "PROCESS"

**ENABLED** = TRUE or FALSE (Boolean).  Allows the Startup Item to be enabled or disabled without being fully removed from the TSS's list

**LAUNCH** = "ONCE" or "MONITOR"  If "ONCE", then the application is launched one time; if "MONITOR", then the application is kept alive - If a user closes it, it will be re-launched by the TSS

**WAIT** = TRUE or FALSE (Boolean)  If FALSE, then the application will be launched as soon as the TSS is launched at startup.  If TRUE, then the application will be launched only after the TSS has detected that the Okuma NC control software has been fully booted, and the THINC API is usable.

**DELAY** = Integer value; Represents the number of milliseconds that the TSS should wait, after the WAIT condition has been met, before launching your application.  For instance, if you want to wait an additional 10 seconds, set this value to 10000

**ARGUMENT** = Any command line argument necessary for your application